# Postgres project analyzer

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, static-code-analysis

I want to do static analysis on Postgres database like here [Design quality report - pgSchema](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/attachment/380/Design%20Quality%20Report.pdf)  or here
 [Project Analyzer report](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/attachment/382/Project%20Analyser%20Report.pdf)

These links provide documents from https://www.postgresql.org/ page, which I found by a google search for "cyclomatic complexity Postgres"

Unfortunately, I can't find in web any information about *Project Analyzer 6.2.04*.

Can you point me to any tool which can do analysis on functions stored in the Postgres database, similar to the link I provided?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis

Comment: This link provides zero information about Postgres specific or even database-specific tools. Also, I don't know how "c" tag can help here

Comment: Sorry, I first thought the report was about the C code of Postgres. So you are looking for a static code analysis tool for PL/pgSQL

Comment: Yes, similar to the first or second link I provided in the question. I cannot find this tool which generated these docs and I think that someone here can know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[plpgsql_check](https://github.com/okbob/plpgsql_check) can do some static analyses

Comment: It is not exactly what I wanted, but it is fine for me, thanks!